# Consulta en arreglo json

Tags: php

Muy buenas amigos del foro, esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien, mi consulta poseo el siguiente código de un arreglo json realizado en php bajo el editor de visual studio code:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="GET"){
$Seccion = $_GET ['Seccion'] ?? NULL;
if ($Seccion) {
    require("conexion1.php");
    $conexion = retornarConexion();
    if ($conexion) {
        $query="SELECT ID,N_Filas,Seccion,Descripcion FROM repuestos WHERE Seccion = ? and Activo = 1 Order By ID asc";
        if ($stmt=$conexion->prepare($query)) {
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $Seccion);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($id, $Filas, $Seccion, $Descripcion);
            $rows=array();
            while($row=$stmt->fetch()){
                $rows[]=array('ID'=>$id,'N_Filas'=>$Filas,'Seccion'=>$Seccion,'Descripcion'=>$Descripcion);
            }
            $stmt->close();
            if ($rows) {                        
                $data=array('data'=>json_decode(json_encode($rows)));
            } else {
                $data=array('error'=>'Registro no ingresado');
            }
        } else {
            $data=array('error'=>'Error en consulta SQL');
        }
        $conexion->close();
    } else {
        $data=array('error'=>'No hay conexión');
    }
} else {
    $data=array('error'=>'No se postearon datos');
}
} else {
$data=array('error'=>'Método no permitido');
}

header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

este me funciona prácticamente en su totalidad, pero no me muestra el campo del ID, tal como se presenta en la siguiente imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

además les presento la estructura de la tabla llamada repuestos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

les cuento además, que este arreglo json siempre lo utilizo para distintas tablas y todo me funciona muy bien, pero en este caso en particular no lo hace, llevo dos días metido en esto y todavía no le encuentro la solución por lo cual requiero de su ayuda, desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Pon siempre el código, las estructuras de las tablas y los resultados de las consultas _como texto, con formato_. [No todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976).

Comment: Empecemos por el principio: ¿seguro que estás verificando el código correcto? ¿Cómo se llama el archivo del código que nos muestras y en qué carpeta está? ¿Vaciaste la memoria caché? Es que no veo motivo para que no muestre el ID, salvo que estés mirando en otro archivo, o en memoria se haya quedado un código viejo.

Comment: Y es que si analizas la respuesta, no es sólo que el `ID` no aparece, sino que se ve un campo `Activo` que no se genera tampoco en este código. En definitiva, el código que nos muestras en la pregunta NO es el código que genera la respuesta que nos muestras en la captura de pantalla. Es algo muy simple de verificar, en Postman tienes la URL, revisa el archivo de esa URL y la lógica que se sigue en él. Si es el código correcto, entonces hay un problema de caché ahí, o de redirecciones.

Comment: El código que muestras no corresponde al resultado, es decir, estas llamando a otro script que no es

Comment: Debuguea **$rows** con un `print_r($rows)` y veras cual es el verdadero resultado.

Comment: @padaleiana te pido mis disculpas de antemano, no fue mi intención, tratare de no cometer este mismo error nuevamente

Comment: @A.Cedano maestro siempre con ayuda y consejos que siempre son bienvenidos, tenias toda la razón, estaba ubicado en otra carpeta en donde hago las pruebas antes de realizar cualquier objetivo, y ese era el problema, es decir el problema era mio.

Comment: @MRDev te comento que tenias toda la razón fue error mío estaba en otra carpeta en donde hago las pruebas y se me olvido el cambiar el nombre de la ruta, mis disculpas por hacerles perder el tiempo

Comment: @OCHOA te comento que tenias toda la razón fue error mío estaba en otra carpeta en donde hago las pruebas y se me olvido el cambiar el nombre de la ruta, mis disculpas por hacerles perder el tiempo

Comment: Nooooo para nada. Es un gusto ayudar. Recuerda Debuguear siempre tu código !!!